# Constraint layout text with button in the bottom

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am doing a constraint layout for screen. And in some small screens is not showing correctly, because the button is over the text.
In the other devices with a bigger screen is showing correctly.

And i don't know how i can solve it.

Thanks

This is my layout (Constraint Layout) with a Linear layout inside.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:background="@color/wf_white">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ly_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/form_margins"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/wf_light_grey">

        <TextView
                style="@style/wf_text_link"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_margins"
                android:text="@string/_BIWC_your_agent"/>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/broker_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/broker_image_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/broker_image_size"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_margin_sides"
                android:src="@drawable/img_broker_without_image"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/broker_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_margins_mini"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_margins_mini"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/broker_icon_phone"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/icons_size_broker"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/icons_size_broker"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_margins_small"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/text_margin_sides"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_action_phone"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/broker_icon_email"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/icons_size_broker"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/icons_size_broker"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_margins_small"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/icons_margin_broker"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/text_margin_sides"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_email"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/broker_icon_location"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/icons_size_broker"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/icons_size_broker"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_margins_small"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/icons_margin_broker"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/text_margin_sides"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_location"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/broker_introduction_title"
            style="@style/wf_text_copy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ly_container"
            android:text="@string/_SR_head"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/access_code_description"
            style="@style/wf_text_hero_copy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/broker_introduction_title"
            android:layout_marginLeft=“20dp”
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/broker_introduction_title"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="@string/_BIWC_welcome_message"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_go_to_register"
            style="@style/wf_button_primary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:text="@string/_BIWC_create_account"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And also i attach a photo of the problem. Where you can see how the button is over the text, and the user can't read the text.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add **`layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf`** & **`layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`**.

> **`layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf`** —> Align the bottom of the desired view
>   to the top of another.
>
> **`layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`** —> Align the top of the desired view to
>   the bottom of another.

```
           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/access_code_description"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf"@+id/btn_go_to_register"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" //Remove this line
```

And

```
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_go_to_register"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/access_code_description"
```

**FYI**

It will be good approach if you use ScrollView ( Where child is ***TextView***).

Comment: Hi.. i cannot set top constraint on my bottom button because as soon as i do it, it shifts above (trying to be in middle of my top layout and the bottom of the screen)..Any help with any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Set ScrollView as parent layout and `ConstraintLayout` in it.

[ScrollView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView)